# jQuery Mobile multi select click event

Tags: jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile, multi-select

How do you trigger the click event on a jQuery Mobile multi-select?

I am trying to add a close button to the select options as I don't feel the (X) close button is straight forward. This topic is discussed here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10004719/jquery-mobile-multi-select-box) with the answer being to:

> you could add Close as an option, then trigger the dialog close method if it is clicked

How to to trigger the click event is not discussed. I have tried the following:

```
$("#selectmenu").change(function() {
alert('Changed!!');});

$(document).delegate('.ui-selectmenu-screen', 'click', function () {
alert('changed');
}).delegate('.ui-selectmenu .ui-btn-inner', 'click', function (event) {
alert('changed2');});

$('#selectmenu').on('change', function () {
alert('changed');});

$('#selectmenu').live('change', function () {
alert('changed');});

$('#pageName').on('click', '.ui-selectmenu-list > li', function () {
alert('changed');});

$("#selectmenu").live( "click", function(event, ui) {
alert('changed');});

$("#selectmenu").bind( "click", function(event, ui) {
alert('changed');});
```

Answer (score 0):

You would use the $.selectmenu() Methods [found here](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0-rc.1/docs/forms/selects/methods.html) and bind to the `change` event like so:

**HTML**

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <select name="selectmenu" id="selectmenu" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="value1">Value 1</option>
        <option value="value2">Value 2</option>
        <option value="value3">Value 3</option>
        <option value="close">Close</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**Close Select Menu**

```
$(document).delegate('#selectmenu', 'change', function(){
    var str = $('#selectmenu option:selected').val(); // Get Value of Option

    if (str == 'close'){
        $('#selectmenu').selectmenu('close');
    }
});
```

**Add Values**

```
function addValues($el){
    var total = 0;
    $('option', $el).each(function(){
        var value = parseInt($(this).val());
            value = (isNaN(value-0)) ? 0 : parseInt(value); // Defaults Value to 0 if NaN

        total += value;
    });
    return total;
}
```

[JSFiddle for Add Values](http://jsfiddle.net/sXkF9/)

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. For some reason I need to use .live rather than .bind for my trigger functions to work. Seeing as it is a multi select I used the following to check whether 'Close' had been clicked:
     if($.inArray('Close',selected) > -1 )
 {
        $('#selectmenu').selectmenu('close');
 }

Is there anyway to remove the 'Close' option from my selectmenu selected list of options after I have left the page? I have a select menu of numbers which I convert to an array of ints that I perform calculations on. Currently the 'Close' option is converted to NaN.

Comment: @user1299792 I would advise using $.delegate() instead of $.live(). For the close option, instead of removing it, you can do a isNan() check and default it to zero or ignore it. I've add a sample Add Values function as an example. Good Luck!